# Install earlier hardware version of the iPhone Simulator?

Tags: iphone, hardware, simulator

I have installed the latest iPhone SDK and the Simulator how allows hardware version 4.0 and 3.2.  Is there a way to add the older hardware versions of the Simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by installing several versions of the SDK in parallel.